# Compiler directive is not set in Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi

I have the following unit implementation in my delphi probject.

```
uses
{$IFDEF Ver270} JSON, {$ELSE} DBXJSON, {$ENDIF}
```

In Delphi XE4 DBXJSON will be implemented - that's fine.
In Delphi XE6 JSON will be implemented - that's fine too.

But in Delphi 10.2, DBXJSON will be implemented - not JSON. Why? Is this a bug in Delphi 10.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is by design. Each version has exactly one `VERXXX` definition. `VER270` is defined in XE6 and XE6 only. For version 10.2 `VER320` is defined.

In your scenario it is much simpler to use code like this:

```
uses
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 27} JSON, {$ELSE} DBXJSON, {$IFEND}
```

Another option is to use a standard include file like `jedi.inc`. This takes the pain out of such conditional statements. If you use `jedi.inc` then you can code it like this:

```
uses
  {$IFDEF DELPHIXE6_UP} JSON, {$ELSE} DBXJSON, {$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Note, in this case, it would probably make more sense to use `RTLVersion` instead of `CompilerVersion`, since this is an RTL change, not a compiler change. Though the two constants are usually kept in sync with the same number, but they can diverge at times depending on updates.

Comment: @Remy Thanks, I've changed it